# Using TortoiseGit in localhost

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I just installed TortoiseGit, which works fine. But when I tried to use it in localhost it crashes. It seems it doesn't have file-access there.

[image: Error]

TortoiseSVN works fine in localhost on my laptop. How can I make TortoiseGit work in localhost?
I'm logged in with an administrator account.

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to create a `git` repo inside IIS's web root?

Comment: Where else would you put it? I develop the website in webroot.

Comment: I cannot speak for others, but I generally do my development in a separate project directory and then have a deployment script that pushes it into `webroot`.

Comment: So every time you make an edit it gets synced with the webroot? What's the point of the extra step?

Comment: For one thing it keeps your Web root clean of things like visual studio project files,  solution files and any other random files that are not needed in a deployment.  One additional benefit is that your Web root will more closely resemble your production deployment which should certainly not have a .git directory.

Comment: You do not have permission to write file to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, you need to run with UAC.